# Deserialization behaviour

Tags: c#, serialization

I have serializable class

```
    [Serializable]        
    public class Entity
    {
        public Guid? SomeId {get;set;}
        ...
    }
```

In DB it has SomeId == null
When restored from DB it has SomeId == Guid.Empty, but if I add emty default constructor it is restored with SomeId == null.
Can anyone explain such behaviour.
Thanks

Comment: How exactly do you save it to the database and how do you restore it?

Comment: What kind of serialization do you use? Is the serialized output written to a database field, or do you use something like a OR mapper?

Answer (score 0):

The empty constructor is required by the serializer to create an instance of the `Entity`. After creating this instance, it will perform its deserialization: setting the individual properties with their serialized values. That is why the property setter must also be public.

To find out your actual problem you can start to verify whether the data has been properly serialized.

I assume you are using [OR mapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) software.
In that case it could also be that the OR mapper is initializing the `SomeId` property with a default value.

Answer (score -1):

Because you use Nullable types **Guid?**,  you add emty default construtor so that SomeId is null.

eg:  if you use public bool? IsTrue { get; set; },the IsTrue property can be assigned the values true or false, or null. details Nullable types in msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Without the empty default constructor, `SomeId` will still be initialized to `null`.